# What is the difference between getcsv() and getcsvfile() methods in magento?

Tags: php, magento, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to Export the AdminHtml Grids to the CSV. I have foud two methods getCsv() and getCsvFile() for Exporting results grid into CSV file. Could you please anyone tell me what is the difference between these two functions?

**Method -1**

```
$fileName = "filename.csv";
$content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('custom_modelue/adminhtml_report_grid')
            ->getCsv();
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```

**Method -2**

```
$fileName = "filename.csv";
$content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('custom_modelue/adminhtml_report_grid')
            ->getCsvFile();
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```

When i use Method -1 The Filters not get applied for the Export CSV Results. But in Method -2, The Filters are aplied to the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There difference between getCsv() and getCsvFile() is below

```
get CsvFile() is 

     Retrieve a file container array by grid data as CSV

     Return array with keys type and value

     return array
```

getcsvFile used to export grid contain to an  csv in magen to system in most of cases

```
  and getCsv() is 
    Retrieve Grid data as CSV
    and return string
```

Answer (score 1):

These are different functions, but with quite similar result.

getCsv() is defined at Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Grid.php

getCsvFile() is defined at Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php